# Can't authenticate google SDK

Tags: python-3.x, google-oauth, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I'm on Mac 10.13.2 and I'm trying to follow the instructions for getting google assistant setup.

I have installed google-assistant-sdk[samples] as well as google-api-python-client as well as google-auth-oauthlib[tool] I believe (all return strings of `Requirement already up-to-date:` when I try to install/upgrade them.

However, as soon as I try this command:
`python3 -m google-oauthlib-tool --client-secrets /Users/eric/Documents/18-01-15\ VoiceSearch/client_secret_xxSECRETNUMBERxx.apps.googleusercontent.com.json --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk-prototype --save --headless`

I get the following error:
`/usr/local/bin/python3: No module named google-oauthlib-tool`

Have I set something up wrong?

Oh and this is what I get when I run `python3 -m pip show google-assistant-sdk
Name: google-assistant-sdk
Version: 0.4.2
Summary: Samples and Tools the Google Assistant SDK
Home-page: https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python
Author: Google Assistant SDK team
Author-email: proppy+assistant-sdk@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: google-auth-oauthlib`

And this is what I get when I run `python3 -m pip show google-auth-oauthlib
Name: google-auth-oauthlib
Version: 0.2.0
Summary: Google Authentication Library
Home-page: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-auth-library-python-oauthlib
Author: Google Cloud Platform
Author-email: jonwayne+google-auth@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: requests-oauthlib, google-auth`

Comment: What is the output of `python3 -m pip freeze`?

Comment: cachetools==2.0.1
certifi==2017.11.5
cffi==1.11.4
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.7
futures==3.1.1
google-api-python-client==1.6.4
google-assistant-grpc==0.1.0
google-assistant-sdk==0.4.2
google-auth==1.3.0
google-auth-oauthlib==0.2.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.5.3
grpcio==1.8.4
httplib2==0.10.3
idna==2.6
monotonic==1.4
oauth2client==4.1.2
oauthlib==2.0.6
protobuf==3.5.1
pyasn1==0.4.2
pyasn1-modules==0.2.1
pycparser==2.18
requests==2.18.4
requests-oauthlib==0.8.0
rsa==3.4.2
six==1.11.0
sounddevice==0.3.10
tenacity==4.8.0
uritemplate==3.0.0
urllib3==1.22

Comment: Is this in a virtual environment?

Comment: No, this is just in the terminal.

Comment: Are you following the instructions here to use a virtual Python environment? https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/embed/install-sample#configure_a_new_python_virtual_environment

Comment: Not sure how to run apt-get commands on a mac, but I'll try to find a tutorial on setting up a virtual Python environment.  Please feel free to share one with me if you have one handy.

Comment: That page results in `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement google-assistant-library (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for google-assistant-library` when running through the commands after setting up the virtual environment.

Comment: The library is not supported on Mac architectures, only the Service: https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/overview#features